# What are the biggest differences between Scala 2.8 and Scala 2.7?

Tags: scala

I've written a rather large program in Scala 2.7.5, and now I'm looking forward to version 2.8. But I'm curious about how this big leap in the evolution of Scala will affect me.

What will be the biggest differences between these two versions of Scala? And perhaps most importantly:

- Will I *need* to rewrite anything?
- Do I *want* to rewrite anything just to take advantage of some cool new feature?
- What exactly are the new features of Scala 2.8 in general?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can find here a [preview of new feature in Scala2.8](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1564) (April 2009), completed with recent [this article](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/06/05/bay-area-scala-enthusiasts-base-meeting-whats-new-in-scala-2-8) (June 2009)

- Named and Default Arguments
- Nested Annotations
- Package Objects
- @specialized
- Improved Collections (some rewrite might be needed here)
- REPL will have command completion (more [on that and other tricks in this article](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/07/19/scala-repl-tips-and-tricks-trunk-only/))
- New Control Abstractions (continuation or break)
- Enhancements (Swing wrapper, performances, ...)

"Rewriting code" is not an obligation (except for using some of the improved Collections), but some features like **[continuation](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096)** ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation): an abstract representation of the control state, or the "rest of computation" or "rest of code to be executed") can give you some new ideas. A good introduction is [found here](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/07/delimited-continuations-explained-in.html), written by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel) (who has also posted a much [more detailed and specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243794/what-are-the-biggest-differences-between-scala-2-8-and-scala-2-7/1245195#1245195) in this thread).

Note: [Scala on Netbeans](http://blogtrader.net/dcaoyuan/entry/scala_plugin_for_netbeans_rewrite) seems to work with some 2.8 nightly-build (vs. the [official page for 2.7.x](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala#section-Scala-ScalaPluginsForNetBeans))

Answer (score 37):

### Taking the Leap

When you migrate, the compiler can provide you with some safety nets.

1. Compile your old code against 2.7.7
   with `-deprecation`, and follow the
   recommendations from all deprecation
   warnings.
2. Update your code to use
   unnnested packages. This can be done
   mechanically by repeatedly running
   this regular expression search
   replace.

   ```
   s/^(package com.example.project.*)\.(\w+)/$1\npackage $2/g
   ```
3. Compile with 2.8.0 compiler, using paranoid command line options `-deprecation -Xmigration -Xcheckinit -Xstrict-warnings -Xwarninit`
4. If you receive errors the error `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scala.reflect.ClassManifest[T]`, you need to add an implicit parameter (or equivalently, a context bound), on a type parameter.

   Before:

   ```
   scala> def listToArray[T](ls: List[T]): Array[T] = ls.toArray
   <console>:5: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type         scala.reflect.ClassManifest[T]
          def listToArray[T](ls: List[T]): Array[T] = ls.toArray                                              ^
   ```

   After:

   ```
   scala> def listToArray[T: Manifest](ls: List[T]): Array[T] = ls.toArray
   listToArray: [T](ls: List[T])(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T])Array[T]

   scala> def listToArray[T](ls: List[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Array[T] = ls.toArray          
   listToArray: [T](ls: List[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T])Array[T]
   ```

   Any method that calls `listToArray`, and itself takes `T` as a type parameter, must also accept the Manifest as an implicit parameter. See the [Arrays SID](http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/7) for details.
5. Before too long, you'll encounter an error like this:

   ```
   scala> collection.Map(1 -> 2): Map[Int, Int]
   <console>:6: error: type mismatch;
    found   : scala.collection.Map[Int,Int]
    required: Map[Int,Int]
          collection.Map(1 -> 2): Map[Int, Int]
                ^
   ```

   You need to understand that the type `Map` is an alias in Predef for `collection.immutable.Map`.

   ```
    object Predef {
        type Map[A, B] = collection.immutable.Map[A, B]
        val Map = collection.immutable.Map
    }
   ```

   There are three types named `Map` -- a read-only interface: `collection.Map`, an immutable implementation: `collection.immutable.Map`, and a mutable implementation: `collection.mutable.Map`. Furthermore, the library defines the behaviour in a parallel set of traits `MapLike`, but this is really an implementation detail.

### Reaping the Benefits

1. Replace some method overloading with named and default parameters.
2. Use the generated `copy` method of case classes.

   ```
     scala> case class Foo(a: Int, b: String)
     defined class Foo

     scala> Foo(1, "a").copy(b = "b")
     res1: Foo = Foo(1,b)
   ```
3. Generalize your method signatures from `List` to `Seq` or `Iterable` or `Traversable`. Because collection classes are in a clean hierarchy, can you accept a more general type.
4. Integrate with Java libraries using Annotations. You can now specify nested annotations, and have [fine-grained control](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/annotation/target/package.html) over whether annotations are targeted to fields or methods. This helps to use Spring or JPA with Scala code.

There are many other new features that can be safely ignored as you start migrating, for example `@specialized` and Continuations.

Answer (score 25):

VonC's answer is hard to improve on, so I won't even try to. I'll cover some other stuff not mentioned by him.

First, some deprecated stuff will go. If you have deprecation warnings in your code, it's likely it won't compile anymore.

Next, Scala's library is being expanded. Mostly, common little patterns such as catching exceptions into `Either` or `Option`, or converting an AnyRef into an Option with `null` mapped into `None`. These things can mostly pass unnoticed, but I'm getting tired of posting something on the blog and later having someone tell me it's already on Scala 2.8. Well, actually, I'm not getting *tired* of it, but, rather, and happily, used to it. And I'm not talking here about the Collections, which *are* getting a major revision.

Now, it *would* be nice if people posted actual examples of such library improvements as answers. I'd happily upvote all such answers.

REPL is not getting just command-completion. It's getting a lot of stuff, including the ability to examine the AST for an object, or the ability to insert break points into code that fall into REPL.

Also, Scala's compiler is being modified to be able to provide fast partial compilation to IDEs, which means we can expect them to become much more "knowledgable" about Scala -- by querying the Scala compiler itself about the code.

One big change is likely to pass unnoticed by many, though it will decrease problems for library writers and users alike. Right now, if you write the following:

```
package com.mystuff.java.wrappers

import java.net._
```

You are importing not Java's `net` library, but `com.mystuff.java`'s `net` library, as `com`, `com.mystuff`, `com.mystuff.java` and `com.mystuff.java.wrappers` all got within scope, and `java` can be found inside `com.mystuff`. With Scala 2.8, only `wrappers` gets scoped. Since, sometimes, you want some of the rest to be in Scope, an alternative `package` syntax is now allowed:

```
package com.mystuff.factories
package ligthbulbs
```

which is equivalent to:

```
package com.mystuff.factories {
  package lightbulbs {
    ...
  }
}
```

And happens to get both `factories` and `lightbulbs` into scope.

Comment: VonC's answer is hard to improve on... yet I believe you did improved it ;) +1

Comment: @Daniel: lol, I just realized I mentioned in my answer an article on continuation... written by you! I edited my answer to give you the proper "attribution" (a bit in the same spirit than http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ )

Answer (score 11):

> Will I *need* to rewrite anything?

```
def takesArray(arr: Array[AnyRef]) {…}

def usesVarArgs(obs: AnyRef*) {
    takesArray(obs)
}
```

needs to become

```
def usesVarArgs(obs: AnyRef*) {
    takesArray(obs.toArray)
}
```

I had to visit the IRC channel for that one, but then realized I should have started here.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a checklist from Eric Willigers, who has been using Scala since 2.2. Some of this stuff will seem dated to more recent users.

> *** Explicitly import from outer packages ***
>
> Suppose we have

```
package a
class B
```

> Change

```
package a.c
class D extends B
```

> to

```
package a.c
import a.B
class D extends B
```

> or

```
package a
package c
class D extends B
```

> *** Use fully qualified package name when importing from outer package ***
>
> Suppose we have

```
package a.b
object O { val x = 1 }
```

> Change

```
package a.b.c
import b.O.x
```

> to

```
package a.b.c
import a.b.O.x
```

> *** When explicitly specifying type parameters in container method calls, add new type parameters ***
>
> Change

```
list.map[Int](f)
```

> to

```
list.map[Int, List[Int]](f)
```

> Change

```
map.transform[Value](g)
```

> to

```
map.transform[Value, Map[Key, Value]](g)
```

> *** Create sorted map using Ordering instead of conversion to Ordered ***

```
 [scalac]  found   : (String) => Ordered[String]
 [scalac]  required: Ordering[String]
 [scalac]         TreeMap[String, Any](map.toList: _*)(stringToCaseInsensitiveOrdered _)
```

> *** Import the implicit conversions that replace scala.collection.jcl ***
>
> *** Immutable Map  .update  becomes  .updated ***
>
> *** Migrate from newly deprecated List methods  --
>   * `elements`
>   * `remove`
>   * `sort`
>   * `List.flatten(someList)`
>   * `List.fromString(someList, sep)`
>   * `List.make`
>
> *** Use List methods
>   * `diff`
>   * `iterator`
>   * `filterNot`
>   * `sortWith`
>   * `someList.flatten`
>   * `someList.split(sep)`
>   * `List.fill`
>
> *** classpath when using scala.tools.nsc.Settings ***
>
> http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/18245/focus=18247
>    settings.classpath.value = System.getProperty("java.class.path")
>
> *** Avoid error: _ must follow method; cannot follow (Any) => Boolean ***
>
> Replace

```
list.filter(that.f _)
```

> with

```
list.filter(that f _)
```

> or

```
list.filter(that.f(_))
```

>
>
>

> *** Migrate from deprecated Enumeration methods  `iterator`  `map` ***
>   Use Enumeration methods  `values.iterator`  `values.map`
>
> *** Migrate from deprecated  `Iterator.fromValues(a, b, c, d)` ***
>   Use  `Iterator(a, b, c, d)`
>
> *** Avoid deprecated type `Collection` ***
>   Use `Iterable` instead
>
> *** Change initialisation order ***
>
> Suppose we have

```
trait T {
  val v
  val w = v + v
}
```

> Replace

```
class C extends T {
  val v = "v"
}
```

> with

```
class C extends {
  val v = "v"
} with T
```

> *** Avoid unneeded `val` in   `for (val x <- ...)` ***
>
> *** Avoid trailing commas ***