# What are Scala continuations and why use them?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, continuations, delimited-continuations

I just finished *[Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed)*, and I've been looking into the changes between Scala 2.7 and 2.8. The one that seems to be the most important is the continuations plugin, but I don't understand what it's useful for or how it works. I've seen that it's good for asynchronous I/O, but I haven't been able to find out why. Some of the more popular resources on the subject are these:

- *[Delimited continuations and Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/1266.html)*
- *[Goto in Scala](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/03/goto-in-scala.html)*
- *[A Taste of 2.8: Continuations](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2096)*
- *[Delimited Continuations Explained (in Scala)](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/07/delimited-continuations-explained-in.html)*

And this question on Stack Overflow:

- *[What are the biggest differences between Scala 2.8 and Scala 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243794)*

Unfortunately, none of these references try to define what continuations are for or what the shift/reset functions are supposed to do, and I haven't found any references that do.  I haven't been able to guess how any of the examples in the linked articles work (or what they do), so one way to help me out could be to go line-by-line through one of those samples. Even this simple one from the third article:

```
reset {
    ...
    shift { k: (Int=>Int) =>  // The continuation k will be the '_ + 1' below.
        k(7)
    } + 1
}
// Result: 8
```

Why is the result 8? That would probably help me to get started.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.continuations.package

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My [blog](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/07/delimited-continuations-explained-in.html) does explain what `reset` and `shift` do, so you may want to read that again.

Another good source, which I also point in my blog, is the Wikipedia entry on [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style). That one is, by far, the most clear on the subject, though it does not use Scala syntax, and the continuation is explicitly passed.

The paper on delimited continuations, which I link to in my blog but seems to have become broken, gives many examples of usage.

But I think the best example of the *concept* of delimited continuations is Scala Swarm. In it, the library *stops* the execution of your code at one point, and the remaining computation becomes the continuation. The library then does something -- in this case, transferring the computation to another host, and returns the result (the value of the variable which was accessed) to the computation that was stopped.

Now, you don't understand even the simple example on the Scala page, so *do* read my blog. In it I'm *only* concerned with explaining these basics, of why the result is `8`.

Comment: I re-read your blog entry and this time I stuck with it -- I think I have a better idea of what is going on.  I didn't get much from the Wikipedia page (I already know Lisp continuations) but the reset/shift deferred style or whatever its called had me stumped.  For the impatient (ie myself) your description was ok but people will have to make sure to stick with it up to the "The result of reset is the result of the code inside shift." paragraph... I was hopelessly lost until that point but it does get clearer!  I will have a look at Swarm because I'm still curious what this is for. Thx!

Comment: Yes, it does take time until things start making sense. I didn't feel I could get away making the explanation any faster.

Comment: It all came together for my when I came to the realization that "reset delimits the scope of the continuation. (ie: the variables and statements to be included.)

Comment: Your explanation was verbose and did not get to the essence of the understanding. The examples were long, I didn't get enough understanding in first paragraphs to inspire me to read it all. So I voted it down. SO displays a msg after I vote, asking me to add a comment, so I am complying. Apologies for my frankness.

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIII No need to apologize. I appreciate the criticism.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. I added my own answer a few moments ago, and you are welcome to feedback if you like.

Comment: I've blogged about this with a focus on understanding control flow (without discussing the details of the implementation). http://www.wherenullpoints.com/2014/04/scala-continuations.html

Comment: Whoa, that kind of blew my mind. I used to imagine giving calculators a "subtract from" operator. That's kind of what this seems to generalize, if I'm understanding.

Answer (score 31):

I found the existing explanations to be less effective at explaining the concept than I would hope.  I hope this one is clear (and correct.)  I have not used continuations yet.

When a continuation function `cf` is called:

1. Execution skips over the rest of the `shift` block and begins again at the end of it

   - the parameter passed to `cf` is what the `shift` block "evaluates" to as execution continues. this can be different for every call to `cf`
2. Execution continues until the end of the `reset` block (or until a call to `reset` if there is no block)

   - the result of the `reset` block (or the parameter to `reset`() if there is no block) is what `cf` returns
3. Execution continues after `cf` until the end of the `shift` block
4. Execution skips until the end of the `reset` block (or a call to reset?)

So in this example, follow the letters from A to Z

```
reset {
  // A
  shift { cf: (Int=>Int) =>
    // B
    val eleven = cf(10)
    // E
    println(eleven)
    val oneHundredOne = cf(100)
    // H
    println(oneHundredOne)
    oneHundredOne
  }
  // C execution continues here with the 10 as the context
  // F execution continues here with 100
  + 1
  // D 10.+(1) has been executed - 11 is returned from cf which gets assigned to eleven
  // G 100.+(1) has been executed and 101 is returned and assigned to oneHundredOne
}
// I
```

This prints:

```
11
101
```

Comment: i've got an error saying "cannot compute type for CPS-transformed function result" when i tried to compile it.. i'm not sure what it is neither how to fix it

Comment: @Fabio Veronez Add a return statement to the end of the shift: change `println(oneHundredOne) }` to, say, `println(oneHundredOne); oneHundredOne }`.

Comment: Nice explanation for a horrible syntax. The declaration of the continuation function is strangely detached from its body. I would be reluctant to share such head-scratching code with others.

Comment: To avoid the `cannot compute type for CPS-transformed function result` error, `+1` shall follow immediately after `oneHundredOne}`. The comments currently residing between them break the grammar somehow.

Answer (score 9):

Given the canonical example from the [research paper](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~rompf/continuations-icfp09.pdf#page=3) for Scala's delimited continuations, modified slightly so the function input to `shift` is given the name `f` and thus is no longer anonymous.

```
def f(k: Int => Int): Int = k(k(k(7)))
reset(
  shift(f) + 1   // replace from here down with `f(k)` and move to `k`
) * 2
```

The Scala plugin transforms this example such that the computation (within the input argument of `reset`) starting from each `shift` to the invocation of  `reset` is *replaced* with the function (e.g. `f`) input to `shift`.

The replaced computation is *shifted* (i.e. moved) into a function `k`. The function `f` inputs the function `k`, where `k` *contains* the replaced computation, `k` inputs `x: Int`, and the computation in `k` replaces `shift(f)` with `x`.

```
f(k) * 2
def k(x: Int): Int = x + 1
```

Which has the same effect as:

```
k(k(k(7))) * 2
def k(x: Int): Int = x + 1
```

Note the type `Int` of the input parameter `x` (i.e. the type signature of `k`) was given by the type signature of the input parameter of `f`.

Another [borrowed](http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/09/continuations-in-scala.html) example with the conceptually equivalent abstraction, i.e. `read` is the function input to `shift`:

```
def read(callback: Byte => Unit): Unit = myCallback = callback
reset {
  val byte = "byte"

  val byte1 = shift(read)   // replace from here with `read(callback)` and move to `callback`
  println(byte + "1 = " + byte1)
  val byte2 = shift(read)   // replace from here with `read(callback)` and move to `callback`
  println(byte + "2 = " + byte2)
}
```

I believe this would be translated to the logical equivalent of:

```
val byte = "byte"

read(callback)
def callback(x: Byte): Unit {
  val byte1 = x
  println(byte + "1 = " + byte1)
  read(callback2)
  def callback2(x: Byte): Unit {
    val byte2 = x
    println(byte + "2 = " + byte1)
  }
}
```

I hope this elucidates the coherent common abstraction which was somewhat obfuscated by prior presentation of these two examples. For example, the canonical first example was presented in the [research paper](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~rompf/continuations-icfp09.pdf#page=3) as an anonymous function, instead of my named `f`, thus it was not immediately clear to some readers that it was abstractly analogous to the `read` in the [borrowed](http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/09/continuations-in-scala.html) second example.

Thus delimited continuations create the illusion of an inversion-of-control from "you call me from outside of `reset`" to "I call you inside `reset`".

Note the return type of `f` is, but `k` is not, required to be the same as the return type of `reset`, i.e. `f` has the freedom to declare any return type for `k` as long as `f` returns the same type as `reset`. Ditto for `read` and `capture` (see also `ENV` below).

---

Delimited continuations do not implicitly invert the control of state, e.g. `read` and `callback` are not pure functions. Thus the caller can not create referentially transparent expressions and thus does not have [declarative (a.k.a. transparent) control over intended imperative semantics](http://copute.com/docs/Event.html#Theory).

We can explicitly achieve pure functions with delimited continuations.

```
def aread(env: ENV): Tuple2[Byte,ENV] {
  def read(callback: Tuple2[Byte,ENV] => ENV): ENV = env.myCallback(callback)
  shift(read)
}
def pure(val env: ENV): ENV {
  reset {
    val (byte1, env) = aread(env)
    val env = env.println("byte1 = " + byte1)
    val (byte2, env) = aread(env)
    val env = env.println("byte2 = " + byte2)
  }
}
```

I believe this would be translated to the logical equivalent of:

```
def read(callback: Tuple2[Byte,ENV] => ENV, env: ENV): ENV =
  env.myCallback(callback)
def pure(val env: ENV): ENV {
  read(callback,env)
  def callback(x: Tuple2[Byte,ENV]): ENV {
    val (byte1, env) = x
    val env = env.println("byte1 = " + byte1)
    read(callback2,env)
    def callback2(x: Tuple2[Byte,ENV]): ENV {
      val (byte2, env) = x
      val env = env.println("byte2 = " + byte2)
    }
  }
}
```

This is getting noisy, because of the explicit environment.

Tangentially note, Scala does not have Haskell's global type inference and thus as far as I know couldn't support implicit lifting to a state monad's `unit` (as one possible strategy for hiding the explicit environment), because Haskell's global (Hindley-Milner) type inference depends on [not supporting diamond multiple virtual inheritance](https://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/browse_thread/thread/3c886611e320f8cb/51e0c505c5beebce?#51e0c505c5beebce).

Comment: [I am proposing](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/MXQ52tlRK6E/KniOsRa-9sAJ) that `reset`/`shift` be changed to `delimit`/`replace`. And by convention, that `f` and `read` be `with`, and `k` and `callback` be `replaced`, `captured`, `continuation`, or `callback`.

Comment: with is a keyword.
P.S. Some of your resets have () which should be {}
Anyway great writeup!

Comment: @nafg thank you, so I will propose `replacement` instead of `with`. Afaik, `()` is also allowed? Afaik, `{}` is ["Scala's lightweight syntax for closures"](http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/09/continuations-in-scala.html), which is hiding an underlying function call. For example, see how [I rewrote Daniel's `sequence`](http://goldwetrust.up-with.com/t112p135-computers#4242) (note that code was never compiled or tested, so please feel free to correct me).

Comment: A block -- that is, an expression containing multiple statements -- requires curly braces.

Comment: @nafg, correct. Afaik `shift` `reset` are library functions, not keywords. Thus `{}` or `()` can be used when the [function expects only one parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4387118/615784). Scala has By-name parameters (see section "9.5 Control Abstractions" of Programming in Scala, 2nd ed. pg. 218), where if the parameter is of type `() => ...` the `() =>` can be eliminated. I assume `Unit` and not by-name because the block should evaluate before `reset` is invoked, but I need `{}` for multiple statements. My usage for `shift` is correct, because it obviously inputs a function type.

Comment: () => cannot be eliminated. Why don't you fire up a REPL?

Comment: @nafg page 219 of Programming in Scala, 2nd ed., has an example with a by-name parameter, and it shows that the `() =>` *is eliminated* from the input argument. Of course the callback function with no input parameters is still created and called behind the scenes, yet it *is eliminated* from the argument syntax. Hehe, you've deduced that I often code Scala only in my head. I do this because I am thinking more big pic conceptually + reductionist about language design for the time being, and don't want to get obfuscated+mired in an explosion of abstruse, pendantic, minutia, diarrhea. :) Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the book, can you give the specific code? Maybe I just misunderstood you. "Can be eliminated" implies that there's an optional syntax, that there are two interchangeable syntaxes. I suspect what you actually are talking about is by-name parameters, which are syntactic sugar that causes x to be treated behind the scenes as ()=>x. ()=>x would likewise be interpreted as ()=>()=>x. Again, this is behind the scenes. The definition syntax is of course =>, without the ().

Comment: @nafg yes I wrote before "By-name parameters". Instead of writing `reset( () => { ... } )`, By-name sugar plus Scala's option to write arguments after the function name separated by a space, allows me to write `reset { ... }` at the function call (i.e. use) site. Yes the declaration of a By-name parameter requires `=>` at the function definition site, e.g. `def reset( param : => Unit )`. Also I assume  `reset( ... )` is also a valid function call, if the `...` evaluates to `Unit`. Terminology, "arguments" are supplied for the "parameters" at the call site.

Answer (score 8):

Continuation capture the state of a computation, to be invoked later.

Think of the computation between leaving the shift expression and leaving the reset expression as a function. Inside the shift expression this function is called k, it is the continuation. You can pass it around, invoke it later, even more than once.

I think the value returned by the reset expression is the value of the expression inside the shift expression after the =>, but about this I'm not quite sure.

So with continuations you can wrap up a rather arbitrary and non-local piece of code in a function. This can be used to implement non-standard control flow, such as coroutining or backtracking.

So continuations should be used on a system level. Sprinkling them through your application code would be a sure recipe for nightmares, much worse than the worst spaghetti code using goto could ever be.

*Disclaimer:* I have no in depth understanding of continuations in Scala, I just inferred it from looking at the examples and knowing continuations from Scheme.

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view, the best explanation was given here: http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.ru/2010/08/delimited-continuations.html

One of examples:

> To see the control flow a little more clearly, you can execute this
>   code snippet:

```
reset {
    println("A")
    shift { k1: (Unit=>Unit) =>
        println("B")
        k1()
        println("C")
    }
    println("D")
    shift { k2: (Unit=>Unit) =>
        println("E")
        k2()
        println("F")
    }
    println("G")
}
```

> Here's the output the above code produces:

```
A
B
D
E
G
F
C
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (more recent -- May 2016) article on Scala continuations is:
"[Time Travel in Scala: CPS in Scala (scala’s continuation)](https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/05/04/time-travel-in-scala-cps-in-scala-scalas-continuation/)" by 
[Shivansh Srivastava (`shiv4nsh`)](https://github.com/shiv4nsh).
It also refers to [Jim McBeath](https://github.com/jimmc)'s [article](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.ru/2010/08/delimited-continuations.html) mentioned in [Dmitry Bespalov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905914/dmitry-bespalov)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724838/6309).

But before that, it describes Continuations like so:

> **A continuation is an abstract representation of the control state of a computer program**.
>   So what it actually means is that it is a data structure that represents the computational process at a given point in the process’s execution; the created data structure can be accessed by the programming language, instead of being hidden in the runtime environment.
>
> To explain it further we can have one of the most classic example,
>
> Say you’re in the kitchen in front of the refrigerator, thinking about a sandwich. You take a continuation right there and stick it in your pocket.
>   Then you get some turkey and bread out of the refrigerator and make yourself a sandwich, which is now sitting on the counter.
>   You invoke the continuation in your pocket, and you find yourself standing in front of the refrigerator again, thinking about a sandwich. But fortunately, there’s a sandwich on the counter, and all the materials used to make it are gone. So you eat it. :-)
>
> In this description, the `sandwich` is part of the **program data** (e.g., an object on the heap), and rather than calling a “`make sandwich`” routine and then returning, the person called a “`make sandwich with current continuation`” routine, which creates the sandwich and then continues where execution left off.

That being said, as announced in [April 2014 for Scala 2.11.0-RC1](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2014/03/06/release-notes-2.11.0-RC1.html)

> We are looking for maintainers to take over the following modules: [scala-swing](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing), [scala-continuations](https://github.com/scala/scala-continuations).
>   **2.12 will not include them if no new maintainer is found**.
>   We will likely keep maintaining the other modules (scala-xml, scala-parser-combinators), but help is still greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Scala Continuations via Meaningful Examples**

Let us define `from0to10` that expresses the idea of iteration from 0 to 10:

```
def from0to10() = shift { (cont: Int => Unit) =>
   for ( i <- 0 to 10 ) {
     cont(i)
   }
}
```

Now,

```
reset {
  val x = from0to10()
  print(s"$x ")
}
println()
```

prints:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

In fact, we do not need `x`:

```
reset {
  print(s"${from0to10()} ")
}
println()
```

prints the same result.

And

```
reset {
  print(s"(${from0to10()},${from0to10()}) ")
}
println()
```

prints all pairs:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5) (0,6) (0,7) (0,8) (0,9) (0,10) (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6) (1,7) (1,8) (1,9) (1,10) (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6) (2,7) (2,8) (2,9) (2,10) (3,0) (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6) (3,7) (3,8) (3,9) (3,10) (4,0) (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5) (4,6) (4,7) (4,8) (4,9) (4,10) (5,0) (5,1) (5,2) (5,3) (5,4) (5,5) (5,6) (5,7) (5,8) (5,9) (5,10) (6,0) (6,1) (6,2) (6,3) (6,4) (6,5) (6,6) (6,7) (6,8) (6,9) (6,10) (7,0) (7,1) (7,2) (7,3) (7,4) (7,5) (7,6) (7,7) (7,8) (7,9) (7,10) (8,0) (8,1) (8,2) (8,3) (8,4) (8,5) (8,6) (8,7) (8,8) (8,9) (8,10) (9,0) (9,1) (9,2) (9,3) (9,4) (9,5) (9,6) (9,7) (9,8) (9,9) (9,10) (10,0) (10,1) (10,2) (10,3) (10,4) (10,5) (10,6) (10,7) (10,8) (10,9) (10,10)
```

**Now, how does that work?**

There is the *called code*, `from0to10`, and the *calling code*. In this case, it is the block that follows `reset`. One of the parameters passed to the called code is a return address that shows what part of the calling code has not yet been executed (**). That part of the calling code is the *continuation*. The called code can do with that parameter whatever it decides to: pass control to it, or ignore, or call it multiple times. Here `from0to10` calls that continuation for each integer in the range 0..10.

```
def from0to10() = shift { (cont: Int => Unit) =>
   for ( i <- 0 to 10 ) {
     cont(i) // call the continuation
   }
}
```

But where does the continuation end? This is important because the last `return` from the continuation returns control to the called code, `from0to10`. In Scala, it ends where the `reset` block ends (*).

Now, we see that the continuation is declared as `cont: Int => Unit`. Why? We invoke `from0to10` as `val x = from0to10()`, and `Int` is the type of value that goes to `x`. `Unit` means that the block after `reset` must return no value (otherwise there will be a type error). In general, there are 4 type signatures: function input, continuation input, continuation result, function result. All four must match the invocation context.

Above, we printed pairs of values. Let us print the multiplication table. But how do we output `\n` after each row?

The function `back` lets us specify what must be done when control returns back, from the continuation to the code that called it.

```
def back(action: => Unit) = shift { (cont: Unit => Unit) =>
  cont()
  action
}
```

`back` first calls its continuation, and then performs the *action*.

```
reset {
  val i = from0to10()
  back { println() }
  val j = from0to10
  print(f"${i*j}%4d ") // printf-like formatted i*j
}
```

It prints:

```
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
   0    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20 
   0    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30 
   0    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40 
   0    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50 
   0    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60 
   0    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70 
   0    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80 
   0    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90 
   0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```

Well, now it's time for some brain-twisters. There are two invocations of `from0to10`. What is the continuation for the first `from0to10`? It follows the invocation of `from0to10` in the *binary code*, but in the source code it also includes the assignment statement `val i =`. It ends where the `reset` block ends, but the end of the `reset` block does not return control to the first `from0to10`. The end of the `reset` block returns control to the 2nd `from0to10`, that in turn eventually returns control to `back`, and it is `back` that returns control to the first invocation of `from0to10`. When the first (yes! 1st!) `from0to10` exits, the whole `reset` block is exited.

Such method of returning control back is called *backtracking*, it is a very old technique, known at least from the times of Prolog and AI-oriented Lisp derivatives.

The names `reset` and `shift` are misnomers. These names should better have been left for the bitwise operations. `reset` defines continuation boundaries, and `shift` takes a continuation from the call stack.

Note(s)

(*) *In Scala, the continuation ends where the `reset` block ends.* Another possible approach would be to let it end where the function ends.

(**) *One of the parameters of the called code is a return address that shows what part of the calling code has not yet been executed.* Well, in Scala, a sequence of return addresses is used for that. How many? All of the return addresses placed on the call stack since entering the `reset` block.

---

UPD **Part 2**
**Discarding Continuations: Filtering**

```
def onEven(x:Int) = shift { (cont: Unit => Unit) =>
  if ((x&1)==0) {
    cont() // call continuation only for even numbers
  }
}
reset {
  back { println() }
  val x = from0to10()
  onEven(x)
  print(s"$x ")
}
```

This prints:

```
0 2 4 6 8 10
```

Let us factor out two important operations: discarding the continuation (`fail()`) and passing control on to it (`succ()`):

```
// fail: just discard the continuation, force control to return back
def fail() = shift { (cont: Unit => Unit) => }
// succ: does nothing (well, passes control to the continuation), but has a funny signature
def succ():Unit @cpsParam[Unit,Unit] = { }
// def succ() = shift { (cont: Unit => Unit) => cont() }
```

Both versions of `succ()` (above) work. It turns out that `shift` has a funny signature, and although `succ()` does nothing, it must have that signature for type balance.

```
reset {
  back { println() }
  val x = from0to10()
  if ((x&1)==0) {
    succ()
  } else {
    fail()
  }
  print(s"$x ")
}
```

as expected, it prints

```
0 2 4 6 8 10
```

Within a function, `succ()` is not necessary:

```
def onTrue(b:Boolean) = {
  if(!b) {
    fail()
  }
}
reset {
  back { println() }
  val x = from0to10()
  onTrue ((x&1)==0)
  print(s"$x ")
}
```

again, it prints

```
0 2 4 6 8 10
```

Now, let us define `onOdd()` via `onEven()`:

```
// negation: the hard way
class ControlTransferException extends Exception {}
def onOdd(x:Int) = shift { (cont: Unit => Unit) =>
  try {
    reset {
      onEven(x)
      throw new ControlTransferException() // return is not allowed here
    }
    cont()
  } catch {
    case e: ControlTransferException =>
    case t: Throwable => throw t
  }
}
reset {
  back { println() }
  val x = from0to10()
  onOdd(x)
  print(s"$x ")
}
```

Above, if `x` is even, an exception is thrown and the continuation is not called; if `x` is odd, the exception is not thrown and the continuation is called.
The above code prints:

```
1 3 5 7 9
```