# How do I enable continuations in Scala?

Tags: scala, continuations

Question says it all.

(Yet, the details of how to get access to the `shift` and `reset` operations has changed over the years. Old blog entries and Stack Overflow answers may have out of date information.)

See also [What are Scala continuations and why use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512930) which talks about what you might want to do with `shift` and `reset` once you have them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Scala 2.12 or 2.11**

The easiest way is to use sbt. Here's what to put in your `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"    
addCompilerPlugin(
  "org.scala-lang.plugins" % "scala-continuations-plugin" % "1.0.3"
    cross CrossVersion.patch)
libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-lang.plugins" %% "scala-continuations-library" % "1.0.3"
scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable"
```

In your code (or the REPL), do `import scala.util.continuations._`

You can now use `shift` and `reset` to your heart's content.

Note that I used a Scala version of 2.12.2 because that's the last version the plugin was published for. If you want to use a newer 2.12.x version, you'd need to build the plugin yourself from source. If you use 2.12.2, you'll probably need to be on Java 8, since according to https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html Java 11 support didn't land until 2.12.4.

**historical information for Scala 2.8, 2.9, 2.10**

You have to start scala (or scalac) with the `-P:continuations:enable` flag.

In your code, do `import scala.util.continuations._`

You can now use `shift` and `reset` to your heart's content.

If you're using sbt 0.7, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/Uj-7zl9n3f4

If you're using sbt 0.11+, see https://gist.github.com/1302944

If you're using maven, see http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-using-continuations-plugin-with-2-8-0-RC1-and-maven-td2065949.html#a2065949

Comment: Note that if you are using the eclipse plugin, put "continuations:enable" in the "P" compiler preferences, and also be sure to clear out the "Xpluginsdir" pref, as the default values in there seem to interfere with using the continuations plugin.

Comment: for Eclipse users, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556540/continuations-in-scala-2-8-1-and-eclipse

Comment: Thank you Mitch Blevins -- I was having trouble until I cleared out the Xpluginsdir pref. Could not find that advice anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I also had to clear the Xpluginsdir field. Furthermore it didn't work until I did a clean.

Comment: Anyone please tell me how to use with gradle?

Answer (score 7):

Non SBT solution:

```
scala -Xpluginsdir /.../scala/lib/ -P:continuations:enable
```

Works on scala 2.11.6, but the plugin/library [said](https://github.com/scala/scala-continuations) that it will no longer be included with Scala 2.12

Comment: Note that perhaps someone will update the plugin to work with 2.12, even though it will definitely no longer be bundled.