# continuations in Scala 2.8.1 and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, continuations

How can i start scala (or scalac) with the -P:continuations:enable flag in Eclipse
I used import scala.util.continuations._; in my code , and need to enable the plugin.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683195/how-do-i-enable-continuations-on-scala-2-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window -> Preferences -> Scala -> Compiler

add continuations:enable to P input box

Comment: Is this still needed in Scala 2.9?

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Preferences -> Scala -> Compiler -> Standard

```
add continuations:enable to P input box
```

Window -> Preferences -> Scala -> Compiler -> Advanced

```
add lib\continuations.jar to XPlugin
```

Window -> Preferences -> Scala -> Compiler -> Build Manager
    sbt

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to switch the Eclipse builder used from **refined** to **sbt**, see: http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/SBT-based_build_manager

However, there is a known bug with that which may or may not occur, see: http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000617-sbt-build-manager-and-certain-compiler-options-don-t-mix (allegedly fixed in latest overnight build).