# Question about Scala continuation

Tags: scala, continuations

As I understand `shift` and `reset` are just library functions. Is it correct that all continuation stuff is implemented as a library and Scala compiler does not do any special work to transform the code inside the `reset` block?

Comment: To use `shift` and `reset` you have to use the continuations compiler plugin. But I cannot tell you what exactly is done by the plugin.

Comment: You will get this error if try to compile without the plugin: `"this code must be compiled with the Scala continuations plugin enabled"` Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683195/how-do-i-enable-continuations-on-scala-2-8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that's not the case. Part of that support is in library and the other part in a compiler plugin. The compiler plugin transforms the code inside reset to continuation-passing form. You need to have this compiler plugin in your build process. In the runtime, scala standard library is sufficient.