# scala: delimited continuation issues

Tags: scala, sbt

Here is a code I have problem to compile.
My question is very simple. 
How to fix compilation error?

I did try to run this from sbt and from command prompt.
SBT configuration below. I did add references to continuation plugin! 
But looks like this is not helping!
See error below.

I've got this from scaladocs: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.8/scala-continuations-library/#scala.util.continuations.package

```
    object MainApp 
    {
       def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = 
       {
        import scala.util.continuations._

         val uuidGen : String = "UniqueValue"

def ask(prompt: String): Int @cps[Unit] =
  shift {
        k: (Int => Unit) => {
        val id = uuidGen
            printf("%s\nrespond with: submit(0x%x, ...)\n", prompt, id)
        }
}

def go =
    reset {
         println("Welcome!")
         val first = ask("Please give me a number")
         val second = ask("Please enter another number")
         printf("The sum of your numbers is: %d\n", first + second)
}

      go

     }
   }
```

[image]

Sbt configuration for the refrences

name := """scala-testing"""

version := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

autoCompilerPlugins := true

addCompilerPlugin(
  "org.scala-lang.plugins" % "scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.6" % "1.0.2")

libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-lang.plugins" %% "scala-continuations-library" % "1.0.2"

fork in run := true

Comment: Could you create a http://scastie.org/ ?

Comment: Never used it before but  here it is: http://scastie.org/15750

Comment: Well, looks like I've manage to resolve it by adding next line to sbt: scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683195/how-do-i-enable-continuations-in-scala