# Rules on using a case statement to destruct a tuple in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val xs = List(('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('b', 4))
```

I want to transform this into a Map. e.g. `Map('a' -> Seq(1,2), 'b' -> Seq(3,4))`. So I proceed to write the transformation:

```
xs.groupBy(_._1) map {
  case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2))
}
```

Why does the brace after the map need to be a `{`. When I started, I assumed I could do the following:

```
xs.groupBy(_._1).map(case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2)))
```

But that doesn't compile.

Comment: By the way, you may use `mapValues`.

Comment: @andyczerwonka your last line will be `xs.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(v => v.map(_._2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the real question here is when can one use parenthesis `(` in place of braces `{` to represent an anonymous function. I recommend having a look at Daniel Sobral's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387118/500314) to the question: [What is the formal difference in Scala between braces and parentheses, and when should they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4386127/500314)

Answer (score 12):

Because .map [method accepts a function](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.scala#L154)

What you've actually written is

```
map({
  case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2))
})
```

and the `{ case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_._2)) }` is a shortcut definition for *pattern matching anonymous function* ([SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), §8.5) which is [one of the function kinds](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html):

```
val isOdd: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
   case x if x % 2 == 1 => x+" is odd"
}

val upcastedIsOdd: Function[Int, String] = {
   case x if x % 2 == 1 => x+" is odd"
}
```

You cannot ommit curly braces (so you'll loose partial function and patten matching nicity) but you can skip plain braces (and still retain partial function) just like in the snippet below:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).take(1)
//res0: List[Int] = List(1)
scala> List(1,2,3) take 1
//res1: List[Int] = List(1)
```

Comment: Of course we know that `map` takes an anonymous function. `listOfIntegers.map(_ * 2)` is also an example of that.