# scala syntax understanding about loop and receive in actor

Tags: scala, actor

I noticed it is legal to write this `scala` code:

```
val fussyActor = actor {
  loop {
    receive {
      case s: String => println("I got a String: " + s)
      case _ => println("I have no idea what I just got.")
    }
  }
}
```

I know from documentation that `actor` is a trait, which has `loop` and `receive` value members. But how is it possible to **stack** these methods like above? Is it implementing or overriding these methods? I am quite confused at this syntax. Please provide some good references/pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a standard disclaimer.  Scala Actors have been deprecated in favor of Akka Actors.  If you want to continue down the path of learning to use Actors with Scala, you should look into Akka instead of researching Scala Actors.

Now, about your question.  There are a couple of things in play here, so let's first start out with what you need to do in order to define a new Scala Actor.  If you look at the Scala Actor trait, you see that there is one abstract method that you must provide called `act():Unit`.  This is a method that takes no inputs and returns no inputs.  It defines the actors behavior.  So in it's simplest form, a custom Scala Actor could be:

```
class MyActor extends Actor{
  def act(){

  }
}
```

Now this not a very interesting actor as it does nothing.  Now, one way to provide behavior is to invoke the `receive` method, providing a `PartialFunction[Any,R]` where R is a generic return type.  You could do that like so:

```
class MyActor extends Actor{
  def act(){
    receive{
      case "foo" => println("bar")
    }
  }
}
```

So now if this actor receives a message "foo", it will print "bar".  The problem here is that this will only happen for the first message and then won't do anything after.  To fix that. we can wrap our call to `receive` with a call to `loop` to make it continue to do the provided `receive` call for each received message:

```
class MyActor extends Actor{
  def act(){
    loop{
      receive{
        case "foo" => println("bar")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So this is now starting to look like your example a bit more.  We are leveraging the `loop` and `receive` methods that come with the `Actor` trait in order to give this actor behavior.  Lastly, instead of defining an explicit class as my actor, I can define one on the fly with the `actor` method on the `Actor` companion object.  That method takes a function body that will be used as the `act` impl like this:

```
def actor(body: => Unit){
  val a = new Actor {
    def act() = body
    override final val scheduler: IScheduler = parentScheduler
  }
}
```

So in your example, you are creating a new actor implementation on the fly and providing an impl for `act` that will loop and call `receive` continually with the partial function you supplied for message handling.

Hopefully this clarifies things a bit.  The only method you are "overriding" (providing an impl for) is `act`.  When you see `loop` and `receive`, those are not overrides; they are simply calls to those existing methods on the `Actor` trait.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So why method calls are called with `{` and `}`?

Comment: @QiangLi, In Scala, `{}` and `()` are interchangable under certain circumstances.  You should check out this link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's illegal without `import Actor._`.

Your code without that import:

```
val fussyActor = Actor.actor {
  Actor.loop {
    Actor.receive { ... }
  }
}
```

`actor`, `loop` and `receive` are methods of object `Actor`.

```
def actor(body: ⇒ Unit): Actor
def loop(body: ⇒ Unit): Unit
def receive[A](f: PartialFunction[Any, A]): A
```

Method [`actor`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/actors/scala/actors/Actor.scala#L126) accepts `by-name` `Untit` parameter `body` - some code block to execute in separate thread and creates an `Actor` with `act` method implemented using parameter `body`.

Method [`loop`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/actors/scala/actors/Combinators.scala#L28) accepts `by-name` `Untit` parameter `body` - some code block to execute in infinite loop.

Method [`receive`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/actors/scala/actors/Actor.scala#L185) accepts `PartialFunction` as parameter `f` and calls `f` with message as parameter. It takes message from actor associated with current thread.

Note that scala actors are deprecated, you should use akka actors. See [The Scala Actors Migration Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html).

Comment: Senia: I am more about asking the **special** syntax than choosing the correct actor model. What is special about this syntax?

Comment: @QiangLi: nothing special. You are just calling 3 methods. I've add descriptions for all methods - see update.