# Convert a Map[String, String] to Map[String, Int] in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I've a Map where the key is a String and the value is an Int but represented as a String.

```
scala> val m = Map( "a" -> "1", "b" -> "2", "c" -> "3" ) 
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)
```

Now I want to convert this into a `Map[String, Int]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
scala> m.mapValues(_.toInt)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)
```

Comment: Beware: unlike most collection transformations in Scala, `mapValues` is lazy - transforming function is applied every single time when referring to map values.

Answer (score 6):

As shown in Brian's answer, `mapValues` is the best way to do this.

You *can* achieve the same effect using pattern matching, which would look like this:

```
m.map{ case (k, v) => (k, v.toInt)}
```

and is useful in other situations (e.g. if you want to change the key as well).

Remember that you are pattern matching against each entry in the `Map`, represented as a tuple2, not against the `Map` as a whole.

You also have to use curly braces `{}`  around the `case` statement, to keep the compiler happy.

Comment: The curly braces are not mandatory, but stylistically better.

Comment: In this particular case (no pun intended), they are required. Replacing them with round parentheses produces: `error: illegal start of simple expression`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4387118/699224