# Real difference between curly braces and parenthesis in scala

Tags: scala, elastic4s

After using Scala for a while and reading about all over the place and especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when)

I was sure I know when to use curlies. as a rule of thumb if I want to pass a block of code to be executed i will use curly braces.

how ever this nasty bug surfaced using elastic4s DSL
using curly braces:

```
bool {
  should {
    matchQuery("title", title)
  }
  must {
    termQuery("tags", category)
  }
}
```

compiles to:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "term" : {
        "tags" : "tech"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

while using parenthesis:

```
bool {
       should (
         matchQuery("title", title)
        ) must (
         termQuery("tags", category)
        )
      }
```

gives the correct result:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "term" : {
        "tags" : "tech"
      }
    },
    "should" : {
      "match" : {
        "title" : {
          "query" : "fake",
          "type" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This was compiled using scala 2.11.6 - Even more confusing is that evaluating the expression in intellij debugger gives correct result no matter what I am using.

I noticed only the last expression was being evaluated why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably problem not in braces, but in infix notation. Look at lines

```
  should {
    matchQuery("title", title)
  }
  must {
```

`must` goes next line, so it is interpreted as new expression but not as continuation of `should`. You probably must place it on the same line with closing brace

```
  should {
    matchQuery("title", title)
  } must {
```

Comment: Great answer. Also explains why it works in the intellij debugger

Comment: The bool construct is the most annoying one to use, I'd be open to suggestions on how to make it clearer.

Also, another gotcha is using sequences with {}, if you have a method that takes multiple params, say `bulk` then you must use () or create a Seq yourself.