# Extended scope in while loops scala

Tags: scala, loops

In scala we can use for loops as follows:

```
for { a <- someCollection
       b = a.someFunc} //inbody we can use b
```

I need similar functionality with a while loop for example:

```
while({ val a = someFunction
         a.isDefined        }) { //do something with a in body }
```

How can I do this in scala?

**EDIT**

I know we can do this using a var on top and modifying it within the loop but I was looking for something more elegant.

What I wish to accomplish is as follows. The function `someFunction` iterates over a collection of `Options` and check for the item that is not a None. If it does not find such an option it returns a None. I can probably do this using

```
for( a <- myCollection
     if a.isDefined) {}
```

but in this case I dont make use of my function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own extended while function, like:

```
def extendedWhile[T](condFunc: => Option[T])(block: T => Unit): Unit = {
  val a = condFunc
  if (a.isDefined) { 
    block(a.get)
    extendedWhile(condFunc)(block)
  }
}
```

Which can be used as:

```
def rand = 
  if ((new scala.util.Random).nextFloat < 0.4) None
  else Some("x")

extendedWhile(rand) {
  x => println(x)
}
// prints out x a random amount of times
```

This `extendedWhile` function is tail recursive, so it should normally be as performant as the regular while loop.

Comment: Quite clever.  I try to avoid inspecting Options directly so I might define `extendedWhile` as follows: `condFunc.foreach { x => block(x); extendedWhile(condFunc)(block) }`

Comment: @jwvh That is indeed a nicer way to define my function.

Comment: @jwvh I agree in general, but in this case tail-recursiveness may be more desirable.

Comment: Like AlexeyRomanov commented, jwvhs version looks nicer, but it looses the better performance of the tail recursion.

Comment: @PeterNeyens How does the usage for it work. I mean in the usage part how is `x=>println(x)` is assigned to block.

Comment: @Sohaib In my example is `x => println(x)` the definition of the `block: T => Unit` parameter.

Comment: @PeterNeyens I have checked that it works but I was thinking it should be something like `extendedWhile(rand) ({
  x => println(x)
})`. Is this some sort of syntactic sugar?

Comment: You can change parentheses to brackets in [some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4387118/5020846).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I like this, but one way to do this is to define the variable as 'var' outside the loop.

```
var a: Boolean = _;
def someFunction: Boolean = true
while({ a = someFunction; a }) {
    println("hi " + a)
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question I already did that but it looks not so 'likeable' as you mentioned.

Comment: I know, it doesn't. I feel that the closure of the while loop predicate doesn't expand inside the body of the while loop, so I am not sure there is a good way to do this without writing your own while loop or using macros.

Answer (score 0):

For is actually syntactic sugar for foreach, map, and flatMap.

So your code above desugars to:

```
someCollection.map { a=> f(a)}.foreach {b => ... //something using b}
```

Now, while is not a desugaring, but an actual imperative syntactic construct.

So the best you can do is

```
var a = true
while (a) {
  a = someFunction (a)
}
```

In practice I never find myself using while, and instead use higher-order functions: like

```
input.takeWhile(_ != '').foreach { //do something }
```