# Strange behaviour in curly braces vs braces in scala

Tags: scala

I've read through several curly braces and braces differences in stackoverflow, such as [What is the formal difference in Scala between braces and parentheses, and when should they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when), but I didn't find the answer for my following question

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val m = Map("foo" -> 3, "bar" -> 4)
    val m2 = m.map(x => {
      val y = x._2 + 1
      "(" + y.toString + ")" 
    })

    // The following DOES NOT work
    // m.map(x =>
    //   val y = x._2 + 1
    //   "(" + y.toString + ")"
    // )
    println(m2)

    // The following works
    // If you explain {} as a block, and inside the block is a function
    // m.map will take a function, how does this function take 2 lines?
    val m3 = m.map { x => 
      val y = x._2 + 2         // this line
      "(" + y.toString + ")"   // and this line they both belong to the same function
    }
    println(m3)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is very simple, when you use something like:

```
...map(x => x + 1)
```

You can only have one expression. So, something like:

```
scala> List(1,2).map(x => val y = x + 1; y)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
List(1,2).map(x => val y = x + 1; y)
...
```

Simply doesn't work. Now, let's contrast this with:

```
scala> List(1,2).map{x => val y = x + 1; y} // or
scala> List(1,2).map(x => { val y = x + 1; y })
res4: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

And going even a little further:

```
scala> 1 + 3 + 4
res8: Int = 8

scala> {val y = 1 + 3; y}  + 4
res9: Int = 8
```

Btw, the last `y` never left the scope in the `{}`,

```
scala> y
<console>:18: error: not found: value y
```

Comment: So it means that for function takes x as argument, if using {}, everything after x => and before the closing }, including multiple lines, belongs to this function? It's just not that intuitive comparing to java/c style of grammer parsing.

Comment: The same is actually true for Java and C. {} delimits a scope, you can put code in a {} block in both Java and C for example to reduce the lifetime of variables. In Java 8, lambdas can be single line without {}, or multiline with {}, so exactly the same as in Scala.