# Pattern matching in anonymous function in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, anonymous-function, type-inference

I'm a beginner Scala developer having problems with a coding exercise (5.12) taken by the book "Functional Programming in Scala" by Paul Chiusano.

I have this function here, called *unfold*, that takes an initial state and a function for producing a stream with the next states:

```
def unfold[A,S](z: S)(f: S => Option[(A,S)]): Stream[A] = f(z) match {
  case Some((h,t)) => h #:: unfold(t)(f)
  case _ => Stream.empty
}
```

For example, with this function one can create an infinite stream of objects, e.g.

`def constant[A](a: A): Stream[A] = unfold(a)(_ => Some(a,a))`

Now, I want to create the Fibonacci sequence, then I type:

`def fibs: Stream[Int] = unfold((0,1))((a,b) => Some(a,(b,a+b)))`

I get these errors:

- Missing parameter type b
- Expression of type Some[((Int,Int),(Nothing,String))] doesn't conform to expected type Option[(A_,(Int,Int))]

If I use the *case* keyword inside the anonymous function passed to *unfold*, like:

`{ case (a,b) => Some(a,(b,a+b))}`

everything's fine.

So my question is: what's the difference between the two implementations? Is it something about type inference that I don't understand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the formal difference in Scala between braces and parentheses, and when should they be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when)

Answer (score 5):

```
 { (a,b) => Some(a, (b, a+b)) }
```

Is a function that takes *two* arguments - `a` and `b`, and returns an option (of a tuple). This is not what you need. You want to define a function that takes a single (tuple) argument. One way to do that would be something like this:

```
 { tuple => Some(tuple._1, (tuple._2, tuple._1 + tuple._2)) }
```

Which you could expand into something like this:

```
 { tuple => 
     val a = tuple._1
     val b = tuple._2
     // Can also do it shorter, with automatic unapply here:
     // val (a,b) = tuple
     // this is already pretty similar to what you have with `case`, right?
     Some(a, (b, a+b))
 }
```

This looks long, but scala has a special syntax construct that lets you deconstruct complex parameters to anonymous functions "on the fly", using syntax similar to pattern matching (it is actually calling `unapply` on the input, same as pattern match would do):

```
 { case(a, b) => Some(a, (b, a+b)) }
```

This is exactly the same as above.

Comment: Compiler is not calling `unapply` here, it knows exact type, `match` works the same way. Looks like `unapply` is only applied to extractor objects.

Comment: @VictorMoroz you are right, tuples are handled specially. I had a generic case in mind when I mentioned `unapply`, you _could_ use an extractor object in this context.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have hit one of the rules about how the compiler interprets your code:

```
A normal function of one arg:

scala> val g = (x: Int) => x + 1
g: Int => Int = <function1>

The data type for a tuple of ints is Tuple2(Int, Int):
scala> (3,4)
res3: (Int, Int) = (3,4)

scala> val a: Tuple2[Int, Int] = (3,4)
a: (Int, Int) = (3,4)

But this does not work:

scala> val f = ((a,b): (Int, Int)) => a+b
<console>:1: error: not a legal formal parameter.
Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
      Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
      or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
val f = ((a,b): (Int, Int)) => a+b
              ^
This works:
scala> val f = (x: Tuple2[Int, Int]) => x._1 + x._2
f: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>
```

This is what you thought you could do:

```
val f = ((a, b): (Int, Int)) => Some(a, (b, a + b))
```

and then (in the context of `unfold`) the (0,1) gets understood as type `(Int, Int)`, so when you call `unfold` you can omit the type declaration and just write `((a, b)) => Some(a, (b, a + b))`. But it does not work because "Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters".
The function `f` above does not compile even on its own, outside of your `unfold`. Instead, this compiles:
`val g = (x: Tuple2[Int, Int]) => Some(x._1, (x._2, x._1 + x._2))`