# scala () vs {} definition of parameter invocation

Tags: scala, scalatest

In the Coursera course "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" Week 1 sample assignment (https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/programming/xIz9O/example-assignment) Martin Ordersky mentions in one of his comments (on line 44 of the ListsSuites.scala test) that

```
   * In Scala, it is allowed to pass an argument to a method using the block
   * syntax, i.e. `{ argument }` instead of parentheses `(argument)`.
```

So when assigning a function definition in Scala would it be equivalent to say:

```
def foo = ()
```

and

```
def foo = {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` or `({})` refers to block of code.

```
{
  statement1
  statement2
  statement3
}
```

and the last statement would be returned.

```
scala> val x = { 
     |  val x = 4 
     |  x + 1
     | }
x: Int = 5
```

While `()` is for one line expression.

### When are {} and () interchangeable

**1.invoking a method with one param**

```
scala> def printlnme(x: String) = { println(x)}
printlnme: (x: String)Unit

scala> printlnme("using parenthesis")
using parenthesis

scala> printlnme{"using braces"}
using braces
```

Not with a method with multiple params,

```
scala> def add(x: Int, y: Int) = { x + y }
add: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

//can also be (x + y) because one line expression
//scala> def add(x: Int, y: Int) = ( x + y )
//add: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> add(1, 2)
res3: Int = 3

scala> add{1, 2}
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but ',' found.
foo{1, 2}
     ^
```

**2.one line expression**

In this example I'm only printing the input.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).foreach { x => println(x) }
1
2
3

scala> List(1, 2, 3).foreach ( x => println(x) )
1
2
3
```

Or, say one line `map` function.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) map { _ * 3}
res11: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9)

scala> List(1, 2, 3) map ( _ * 3 )
res12: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9)
```

But `()` alone can not be used with multiline statements

```
scala> :paste

List(1, 2, 3) foreach ( x =>
     val y = x * 28
     println(y)
)

<console>:2: error: illegal start of simple expression
     val y = x * 28
     ^
```

you still need `({})` to be able to use parenthesis for multiline.

```
scala> :paste

List(1, 2, 3) foreach ( x => {
     val y = x * 28
     println(y)
})

28
56
84
```

Answer (score 3):

That's defining a method/def - the comment is referring to when calling the def

```
scala> def foo(arg1: Int) = arg1 + 1
foo: foo[](val arg1: Int) => Int

scala> foo(1) // round parenthesis
res0: Int = 2

scala> foo{1} // bracket parenthesis
res1: Int = 2
```

Also note the body of the def does not need to be enclosed in parenthesis. So using your example, all of the following are equivalent:

```
def foo = (???) // ??? means implementation not yet defined
def foo = {???}
def foo = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in your case: yes, they will both result in `foo: Unit`

In many cases they will effect the same due to both evaluating to expressions, but strictly speaking they are different. `{}` is an empty block which evaluates to `Unit` because it's (absent) last statement evaluates to `Unit`, whereas `()` is the default value of the `Unit` type.

This question has come up [long ago](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/2593), and imo the key point regarding your particular question is that you cannot use the `{}` syntax with functions that take more than 1 argument (non-curried). Extensive coverage of other cases can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when). Generally those two are different; they just frequently happen to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

To give you brief answer, both are representation of memory blocks but it differs in terms of how much the blocks can accommodate.

*{} is for multiple line definitions*

```
 Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map { x =>
      x + 1
      x - 1
    }
```

*() is for single line definition*

```
   Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(x =>
      x + 1
      x -1)
```

The above code will give you compiler error as it can accommodate only single line .***But you can also use {} inside ()*** to accommodate more than one lines as follows

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(x => {
  x + 1
  x - 1
})
```