# What do these Scala statements mean? and what do you call this syntax? [infix notation]

Tags: scala, infix-notation

I am trying to figure out some Scala code. Here's a snippet that creates an mutable Map and Ordering object.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val score = mutable.Map(start -> 0d) withDefaultValue Double.PositiveInfinity
val priority = Ordering by {n: Node => score(n) + heuristic(n)}
```

What do you call this code where you just put terms after an expression without commas or parenthesis? I have a feeling this is the functional aspect of Scala but not sure. Do the curly brackets have a different meaning in this context?

Comment: The compiler adjusts (or "de-sugars") `2 + 3` into the more syntactically correct `2.+(3)`. That adjustment can be applied to any type (like `Int`) with a method (like `+`) that takes a single argument (`3` in this example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do you call this code where you just put terms after an expression without commas or parenthesis?

This is using 'infix notation', see http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html

> I have a feeling this is the functional aspect of Scala but not sure.

This is 'syntactic sugar' and not directly related to functional programming.

> Do the curly brackets have a different meaning in this context?

In this context, curly braces define a expression block.
More detailed discussion available here:
[What is the formal difference in Scala between braces and parentheses, and when should they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when)