# foreach loop in scala

Tags: scala, foreach

In scala foreach loop if I have list

```
val a = List("a","b","c","d")
```

I can print them without a pattern matching like this

```
a.foreach(c => println(c))
```

But, if I have a tuple like this

```
val v = Vector((1,9), (2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (5,5))
```

why should I have to use

```
v.foreach{ case(i,j) => println(i, j) }
```

1. a pattern matching case
2. { brackets

Please explain what happens when the two foreach loops are executed.

Comment: It is design flaw in scala. There is probably explanation for this, but it will be long and mainly useless.

Comment: According to the Dotty team in Scala 3 this will be valid:

`v.foreach((i,j) => println(i, j))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have to, you choose to. The problem is that the current Scala compiler doesn't deconstruct tuples, you can do:

```
v.foreach(tup => println(tup._1, tup._2))
```

But, if you want to be able to refer to each element on it's own with a fresh variable name, you have to resort to a partial function with pattern matching which can deconstruct the tuple.

This is what the compiler does when you use `case` like that:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val v: List[(Int, Int)] = scala.collection.immutable.List.apply[(Int, Int)](scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Int](1, 2), scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Int](2, 3));
  v.foreach[Unit](((x0$1: (Int, Int)) => x0$1 match {
    case (_1: Int, _2: Int)(Int, Int)((i @ _), (j @ _)) => scala.Predef.println(scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Int](i, j))
  }))
}
```

You see that it pattern matches on unnamed `x0$1` and puts `_1` and `_2` inside `i` and `j`, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

According to http://alvinalexander.com/scala/iterating-scala-lists-foreach-for-comprehension:

```
val names = Vector("Bob", "Fred", "Joe", "Julia", "Kim")

for (name <- names)
    println(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer #2: You can only use `case` in braces. A more complete answer about braces is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when).

Answer (score 1):

**Vector** is working a bit differently, you using function literals using case...

In Scala, we using brackets`{}` which accept `case`...

```
{
  case pattern1 => "xxx"
  case pattern2 => "yyy"
}
```

So, in this case, we using it with foreach loop...

Print all values using the below pattern then:

```
val nums = Vector((1,9), (2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (5,5))

nums.foreach {
    case(key, value) => println(s"key: $key, value: $value")
}
```

Also you can check other loops like for loop as well if you think this is not something which you are comfortable with...