# Why in some cases, I cannot use {} when passing arguments

Tags: scala

In following definitions, I can use `{}` instead of `()` for curried functions but not for regular functions. Why?

```
//curried
scala> def add(i:Int)(j:Int) = {i+j}
add: (i: Int)(j: Int)Int

scala> add(1)(2)
res19: Int = 3

//{} works
scala> add(1){2}
res20: Int = 3

//{} works again
scala> add{1}{2}
res21: Int = 3

//non curried
scala> def add(i:Int,j:Int) = {i+j}
add: (i: Int, j: Int)Int

//use of {} creates error
scala> add{1,2}
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but ',' found.
add{1,2}
     ^
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` is **code block**, the last value in **code block** is the **return value** of this.

- for `add(1){2}` means the second code block **return value 2** as the second parameter
- for `add{1}{2}` means: first code block return `1` as parameter, second code block return `2` as second parameter

so for `add{1,2}` doesn't have any meaning, this is not a correct syntax.