# scala method call trick List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0) _+_

Tags: scala

I came from [What is the formal difference in Scala between braces and parentheses, and when should they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24985146/5366394)
, so still I am not clear understand the scala method call syntax trick. I think the lcn's answer in the link is clear but what does these mean:

```
val r = List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0) _+_ //r: String => String = $Lambda$1642/1200068083@562c1af9
val l = r{"hello"} //l: String = $Lambda$1643/1458648440@23ae6386hello
```

1. why `r` is a function? and call it return another function `l` and can not call `l`?
2. are there some official doc for method call in () and {}?

Comment: That's a totally misleading way to write it down. At least `.foldLeft(0) _ + _` doesn't suggest that `_` and `_` somehow belong together. The linked answer didn't attempt to generate any optical illusions by removing all spaces in `_+_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with operator precedence:

```
val r = List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0) _+_
```

Is equivalent to:

```
val r = (List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0) _) + _
```

Which means - we take the *partially applied* `foldLeft` function, `List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0) _`, which has the type `((Int, Int) => Int) => Int)`, and we call `+ _` on it.

Now - Scala compiler tries to figure out what the `+` operator should mean for a Function, and since `Function` does not define such an operator, it does the best it can to find a suitable *implicit conversion*, and finds that indeed the `Function` can be converted to a `String` using its `toString` method, so that the `+ _` means "a new anonymous function that appends any input String passed to the String representation of the `List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0) _` function".

So we end up with a `String => String` function, that appends the input to the `toString` result of the function `List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0) _`, which is `"<function1>"`:

```
scala> val r = List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(0) _ + _
r: String => String = <function1>

scala> r("a")
res5: String = <function1>a

scala> r(" bbbb")
res6: String = <function1> bbbb
```

Comment: A small inaccuracy: the implicit conversion is performed not to `String`, but to `scala.runtime.StringAdd`, a class that has only a single method `def +(other: String)`