# () vs {} in foreach case

Tags: scala, foreach, case

In my Scala code below, use foreach to loop through a Tuple List,

```
val t1 = List((1,"A"), (2, "B"))

t1.foreach{
  case(id, name) => println(id, name)
}

t1.foreach(x => println(x))

t1.foreach(case(id, name) => println(id, name))

error: illegal start of simple expression
           t1.foreach(case(id, name) => println(id, name))
                      ^
```

Why {} works, first () works, but last () return an error ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when - specifically, check out "Function/Partial Function literals with case" section in the accepted answer.

Comment: scala>    ` t1.foreach( x =>
     |       x match (case(id, name) => println(id, name))`
<console>:2: error: '{' expected but '(' found.
             x match (case(id, name) => println(id, name))

Comment: This works:      ''' t1.foreach( x => 
      x match {case(id, name) => println(id, name)}
    ) '''

Comment: Seems `match` needs to be followed with {}