# Scala Nested expression does not take parameters

Tags: java, scala

Team,

New to scala and learning step by step. while learning nested scopes in expression blocks, wrote below lines of code

```
object ExpressionTest extends App {


  val area = {
    val PI = 3.14
    PI * 10
    {
      val PI= 100
      PI * 2
    }
  }

  println(area)
}
```

Getting below exception at runtime .

```
Error:(9, 5) Int(10) does not take parameters
I am using Intellji
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala it is possible to specify a function parameter as a block. The compiler thinks that your inner block is a parameter to `10` from the previous line.

To help the compiler understand what you mean, you can add a `;` at the end of the line:

```
 val area = {
    val PI = 3.14
    PI * 10;
    {
      val PI = 100
      PI * 2
    }
  }
```

Comment: @krylog: after adding ; it is working fine as expected. Can you please provide simple example for what does it mean? "it is possible to specify a function parameter as a block." - bit confuse with functional programming

Comment: You can, for example, write `someList.foreach { x ⇒ println(x) }` instead of `someList.foreach(x ⇒ println(x))`. That's what the parser thinks you are doing in your case. This allows you to write methods that *look like* built-in control structures, even though they are library methods.

Comment: There's also a comprehensive answer about parenthesis and curly braces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when).

Comment: An empty line after `PI * 10` is more idiomatic than a semicolon.