# How to interpret function value wrapped in curly braces (ammonite issue)

Tags: scala, ammonite

After reading [What is the formal difference in Scala between braces and parentheses, and when should they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4386127/1602266), I still don't know how to understand function value wrapped in `{}`.

Consider the following two REPL sessions:

```scala
@ val f = { (x: Int) =>
    x
    val y = x
    y
  }
f: Int => Int = ammonite.$sess.cmd30$$$Lambda$1765/0x0000000801346840@24c7b944
```

```scala
@ { (x: Int) =>
    x
    val y = x
    y
  }
cmd31.sc:3: not found: value x
  val y = x
          ^
Compilation Failed
```

I have several questions.

1. Why the first snippet compiles while the second doesn't? In the first snippet, compiler knows the `{...}` as a whole is a function value. In the second snippet, only the `(x: Int) => \n x` part is function value (Sorry about the `\n` to indicate line break). Why?
2. Regarding the `{ (x: Int) => \n ... }`, when is it interpreted as function value and when is it not?
3. Is the curly brace (`{}`) part of the function value, or only `(...) => ...` inside is function value? If it is a part it, does the form have a name? For example, I think `(_ + _)` could be called function value's placeholder syntax.

---

Update: This is purely an Ammonite issue. See answer for detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is ammonite.

Scala REPL has a paste mode allowing you to paste multiple lines before evaluating:

```
:paste
sealed trait X
class Implementation extends X // impossible without doing it at once
// Ctrl+D
```

Ammonite doesn't have such paste mode, but it [allows you to perform multi-line](https://ammonite.io/#BlockInput) copy paste... but wrapping them all in `{}` which ammonite would unwrap. So your code:

```
{ (x: Int) =>
  x
  val y = x
  y
}
```

is seen by compiler as

```
(x: Int) =>
  x // end of function definition
val y = x // new variable calling x, which isn't defined anywhere
y // call to undefined y, because previous line failed
```

The first example works because you have `val f =`  so ammonite's parser cannot assume that *all of your code* is within one block, so it doesn't strip it before passing it into compiler.

As docs suggest if you don't want this behavior you should add another layer of curly brackets:

```
{{ (x: Int) =>
  x
  val y = x
  y
}}
```

This isn't a compiler and language specification issue as much as issue with some particular REPL implementation.

Comment: Oh my... 1 hour wasted by ammonite... Thank you for helping me out. (Ok, Shouldn't blame ammonite. Just read the doc...)

Comment: No problem, I think I got burned by this as well, this is quite convenient if you know about it (more than writing `:paste` and then closing it with Ctrl+D) but if you aren't aware it's an annoying pitfall.