# Understaning how function literals created with braces work

Tags: scala

[Quoting from this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387118/1525061)

"Scala has a syntax for function and partial function literals. It looks like this":

```
{
    case pattern if guard => statements
    case pattern => statements
}
```

How does it work and under what circumstances can you create a function literal with brace `{}` instead of the arrow `=>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pattern Matching Anonymous Function](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions)

```
{ case pattern => value }
```

is equivalent to

```
x => x match { case pattern => value }
```

and depending on the expected type becomes either `PartialFunction` or `FunctionN`.

For example,

```
val f: Int => String = { case x => "" }
```

becomes

```
val f: Int => String = (x: Int) => x match { case x => "" }
```

which is equivalent to

```
val f: Function1[Int, String] = new Function1[Int, String] {
  def apply(x: Int): String = x match {
    case x => ""
  }
}
```

because the expected type is `Int => String`

whilst

```
val f: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case x => "" }
```

becomes

```
val f: PartialFunction[Int, String] = new PartialFunction[Int, String[] {
  def apply(x: Int): String = x match { 
    case x => "" 
  }

  def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = {
    case x => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

because the expected type is `PartialFunction[Int, String]`.

Therefore pattern matching anonymous function expression with braces can be used wherever the corresponding expanded versions would be accepted according to the expected type.

---

As a side note, consider the similarity between pattern matching anonymous functions in Scala and [piecewise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) function definition in mathematics

> In mathematics, a piecewise-defined function (also called a piecewise
> function, a hybrid function, or **definition by cases**) is a function
> defined by multiple sub-functions, where each sub-function applies to
> a different interval in the domain.

Comment: I'd just like to add that `{ case (x, y) => foo }` can also be a function taking two arguments instead of a single 2-tuple.