# Building a reverse proxy

Tags: scala, programming-languages, node.js, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm building a reverse proxy from scratch. The requirements are:

1) Super scalable. It must handle a lot of concurrent requests (also streaming, 1000 request/second would be a good performance in my case)
2) Super fast (non blocking).
3) No C/C++ or Erlang
4) Easy to mantain - even if it was, Assembly is not an option :)

After some research, most of people suggests using `node.js` or `Scala` - what do you think is the best solution for this kind of job? Which technologies would you use to build this kind of proxy?

Thanks

Comment: Super scalable and fast is not a very clear requirement. Do you have a more quantifiable use case?

Comment: node.js can handle it. I don't really know the advantages of node.js vs Scala but I like node so that's got my vote ;)

Comment: There are some pretty good high-performance reverse proxies out there all ready... Nginx, HAProxy etc. What does yours need to do that they don't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I'd try out the Scala [Finagle](https://github.com/twitter/finagle) library first.

Just to expound a bit, people who said "try Node.js or Scala" are slightly misguided in that Scala—like Java—is just a programming language, whereas Node.js is most of a platform.  Apart from its general advantages, the main things Scala brings to the table for this kind of project are:

1. A juicy bit of syntax that makes it easier to write actor systems as libraries, namely PartialFunction "literals":

```scala
   trait NeedsAPF {
     def pf: PartialFunction[Any,Unit]
   }

   object PFHaver extends NeedsAPF {
     def pf = {
       case i: Int => println("I got an int and it was " + i)
     }
   }
```

2. When you're ready for it, a [continuations plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512930/what-are-scala-continuations-and-why-use-them), which lets you write code that looks synchronous, but can be asynchronous under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) as it satisfies all of your requirements.  I'm not sure why there's a need to build it from scratch, but I suppose if you decide to build it in node, you can certainly at least take inspiration from this.

Answer (score -2):

Scala should be good enough, but you'll need to use NIO a lot, which means you'll probably be in close contact with *Java's* NIO library. I don't know if any of the libraries available in Scala will help you in this.