# Scala: Delimited Continuations Explained - Not

Tags: scala, continuations, delimited-continuations

Interested in the concept of continuation, I started reading wikis, posts, and came to this "simple" example:

```
reset {
  ...
  shift { k: (Int=>Int) =>  // the continuation k will be the '_ + 1' below
    k(7)
  } + 1
}
// result: 8
```

Without knowledge of Scala, I'm totally lost here, could not figure out how the 8 comes out.

Below is how I tried to figure out the meaning but failed. Any guy could you please give me a short explanation? Yeah there are Scala grammar books but they are too thick, I'm more interested in understanding delimited continuation concept than master Scala language...

- `(Int=>Int)`

  Looks like a C# delegate, input is Int, output is Int.
- `k: (Int=>Int) => k(7)`

  I'm lost here... what is k, and what is (Int=>Int)=>k(7)?
- `shift { k: (Int=>Int) => k(7) } + 1`

  Even more lost...
- `reset { ...; shift { k: (Int=>Int) => k(7) } + 1 }`

  Even even more and more lost...

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512930/what-are-scala-continuations-and-why-use-them) and its answers.

Comment: I think that you only making this task much more harder for yourself, when you trying to understand non-trivial Scala code "Without knowledge of Scala". I recommend you to learn the basics of the language, like syntax, first. There are a lot of [books](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/959) and [other resources](http://docs.scala-lang.org/) out there.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuations?

Comment: yeah Matthew, my thread is Continuation @ wiki => Delimited Continuation @ wiki (lost as the example) => http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/07/delimited-continuations-explained-in.html => stackoverflow here .... but thanks your guys seems now i got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found Chris League's talk, "Monadologie: Professional Help for Type Anxiety" (http://vimeo.com/13304075) contains one of better examples of a delimited continuation.

Answer (score 1):

fotNelton, thanks a lot! Alex Neth's answer in the link helped me out. Now I think I got it. Let me answer my own question to dot down as a note.

Grammar of reset and shift:

```
reset {
  ...
  shift { cf: (InputParameterType => OutpututParameterType) =>
     CodeBlockInsideShift
  } 
  CodeBlockAfterShiftBeforeEndOfReset
}
```

It actually means, in C# style pseudo code:

```
public delegate OutpututParameterType CFDelegate(InputParameterType);

CFDelegate cf = CodeBlockAfterShiftBeforeEndOfReset;

CodeBlockInsideShift;
```