# Is this online Scala book still relevant for Scala 2.8?

Tags: scala

[This book](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com) seems really good. Is it still relevant for Scala 2.8, given that it was published in 2008?

Comment: Just take the new features and change deltas into account and ... sure (but if it costs $, there are likely better approaches ;-). One *big* 2.7/2.8 difference is the the standard collection library for which there is at least one nice write-up (perhaps more) by Odersky + others.

Comment: The major core of the language hasn't changed much, so to learn about the stuff like syntax, structure, first-class functions, etc., it works just fine. And take a look at these links: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_47.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243794/what-are-the-biggest-differences-between-scala-2-8-and-scala-2-7

Comment: The 2nd edition of that book is coming up soon and is already available in early access form: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033073.do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. They don't cover some of the newest material, but in those cases there are many good online writeups, such as:

- The new collections API: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html
- The architecture of the new API (gives a good deal of insight to the more subtle features added in 2.8 which made the new API possible): http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html
- Package objects: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html#

etc. Payne and Wampler do point out a lot of the new features where they were known ahead of time and, as I recall, nothing they wrote changed in such a significant way to make what they said inapplicable.

UPDATE:

As asked in the comments, the actor and parser combinator libraries also had some changes. The actor library now includes the Reactor trait (discussed here http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2041) and the parser combinator library now includes a packrat parser implementation. There is a fairly complete (as far as I know) list of the changes in 2.8 here: http://sites.google.com/site/scalatohoku/changes-and-improvements-on-scala-2-8

Comment: What about things like actors and parsing? Have they changed a lot too?

Comment: Actually, yes, both of those libraries had somewhat significant changes. The actor library got the addition of the Reactor trait (that and other changes are described here http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2041) and the parser combinator library now uses the packrat parser implementation. A good summary of all the changes is available here: http://sites.google.com/site/scalatohoku/changes-and-improvements-on-scala-2-8

Comment: Packrat is optional, actually. The original parser combinator is all there.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks -- I actually meant to write "includes" where I typed "uses." I appreciate your pointing that out.

Comment: I added the details in my earlier comment to the answer and made the correction Daniel pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the discussion of *Programming Scala* (Payne and Wampler), the first edition of *Programming **in** Scala* (Odersky, Spoon, Venners) was excellent, and I'm sure the [second edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed), which came out recently and covers 2.8, is even better. (Also available for significantly less [from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644), although AFAICT you don't have the option of getting the PDF that way.)